# WP how to display for post that he was published '2 months ago'

Tags: wordpress, date, date-format

Wordpress question.
I need to display post's date but in form for example '2 months ago'. 
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [human_time_diff()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff) function for this. From the documentation:

```
<?php
// To print an entry's time (eg.: "2 days ago"): 
echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago';
?>
```

Place the code above anywhere inside [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) and you're good to go.